# Execute a BASH script... by double-clicking on it?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, high-sierra

Is it possible to execute a bash script by double-clicking on it? The shell script executes with `$ ./script.sh` without issues.  Double-clicking the script opens TextEdit. It would be nice to execute by clicking on it...

```
$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 
Software:

System Software Overview:

  System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
  Boot Volume: lily
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
  User Name: System Administrator (root)
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
```

Comment: It's going to be confusing if you say your script is .sh and not .command - you need to have that for click to work out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe change the extension name to .command, but I think there should be some workaround to make .sh work.

To run by double click on the icon:
open terminal and cd to directory of script.
then chmod +x .
finder will decide if it is excutable or not.

Comment: thanks. as i mentioned, the script runs fine, it has permission to execute

Comment: @lily If you save the script to your desktop and open it with Finder - can you take read/write ownership of it entirely - then double check `chmod a+x` and drop the icon to the command line window and make sure execute is set? It's likely a permissions issue and putting it on your desktop and using Finder to fix ACL/ownership should clarify if that's the case with where and how you stored the file - not that you don't have .command set properly.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to your Terminal or iTerm.
2. Change to directory where your file is located.
3. Type the following:

   `chmod a+x (yourscriptname)`
4. Right click on your file and select **Open with** and **Other**.
5. Enable **All Applications** and choose **Terminal**.
6. **NOTE**: If you always want to open that file with Terminal, then check **Always Open With**.
7. Finally, double click on your file and it should work.